# Securing user input outputted in html with coldfusion

Tags: html, coldfusion, user-input, xss

When an user searchs a page I add ?q=[searchterm] to my URL and output something like this:

```
Your search result for <CFOUTPUT>#htmleditformat(URL.q)#</CFOUTPUT>:
```

A while ago I read that `htmleditformat()` is not enough and XSS can still be executed
(... for example if somebody sends a link to a victim like http://example.com/?q=[evilXSS]).

I also save `URL.q` to a database (I'm using ORM in this case):

```
<CFSET myobject.setKeyword(URL.q) />
```

but for now I'm intereseted how to securely output the userdata to the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `xmlFormat()`, described [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e62.html). It escapes more characters than `htmlEditFormat()` such as Single-quotation marks and high ASCII characters in the range 159-255.

If you want more control you can use Javas [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) directly.

Comment: Thanks! I just found a post of Ben Nadel where the use of `xmlformat()` over `htmleditformat()` is suggest in the comments, too. Seems to be best practise. For others searching for it: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2004-Escaping-Form-Values-Understanding-The-ColdFusion-htmlEditFormat-Life-Cycle.htm